# Add class on li element (filter) depending on url hash

Tags: php, jquery, hash, filter, custom-data-attribute

in order to have a filter link with instruments already filtered, I'm trying to add classes on "a links" depending on data-attributes in URL (hash).
I'm not using input [checkbox] for the filter list/terms.

The website is on Wordpress and I'm using this awesome plugin for the filter : https://github.com/Robbertdk/wordpress-ajax-filter-posts

JS code based on : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796926/8544865

Filter terms example :

```
<div class="ajax-posts__filterlist">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="disabled" data-term="filter-term1"><span>Instrument 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="disabled" data-term="filter-term2"><span>Instrument 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="disabled" data-term="filter-term3"><span>Instrument 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="disabled" data-term="filter-term4"><span>Instrument 4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="disabled" data-term="filter-term5"><span>Instrument 5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery

1/ adding data-term="value" on url. Url will be like: http://website/our-instruments/#term1+term2+term3 (if term1/2/3 are manually checked) :

```
var hash = $(".ajax-posts__filterlist ul a.chkd-el").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("term");
    }).toArray();
    hash = hash.join("+");
    location.hash = hash;
```

2/ here is the part where I have troubles. I want to add classes only on  elements corresponding on data-term value. I'm able to put all values from URL on data, but I can't use them to add classes on correct elements :

```
if (location.hash !== "") {
        var hash = location.hash.substr(1).split("+");

        hash.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // return right strings term1, term2, etc...

        $(".ajax-posts__filterlist ul a[data-term=" + data + "]").addClass("is-active enabled chkd-el"); // that line is not working
    });
}
```

3/ I guess I will need a trigger to simulate checked element (ajax is used for the filter process, with click Event Listeners)

Here the whole JS code :

```
var $checkedEl = $(".ajax-posts__filterlist a");

$checkedEl.on("click", function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("chkd-el") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("chkd-el");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("chkd-el");
    }   

    var hash = $(".ajax-posts__filterlist ul a.chkd-el").map(function() {
        return $(this).data("term");
    }).toArray();
    hash = hash.join("+");
    location.hash = hash;   

    if (location.hash !== "") {
        var hash = location.hash.substr(1).split("+");

        hash.forEach(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".ajax-posts__filterlist ul a[data-term=" + data + "]").addClass("is-active enabled chkd-el");
        }); 
    }
});
```

I hope my problem is understandable.

Thanks !

Comment: in which way these code triggerd? `if (location.hash !== "") {...}`

Comment: It's triggered on click on `$(".ajax-posts__filterlist a");`